# How can I use Mouse and Touch events in the same button?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, mouseevent

I have a button with `Click="Window_Click"` and `TouchDown="Window_Touch"`. When I click in *non touch devices* it works just fine, but when I click in *touch devices*, sometimes I have another button in focus and the touch trigger two events. Basicaly when I touch the button, they execute both events, how can I create just one event for both behaviors or how can I "stop"/don't execute clicks events when I touching things?

```
private void Window_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    functionOne();
}
private void Window_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    functionOne();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch and handle duplicate calls to the event. You could try setting a handled boolean so the click event knows if the touch event handled the event or not (the touch event should be firing first). Something like this...

```
private bool handled = false;
private void Window_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(!handled)
    functionOne();
}
private void Window_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    handled = true;
    functionOne();
}
```